# MERGEFIELD for Values with Superscript for dates Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-word, mergefield

Having `1{sup|er} janvier 2012` for the MergeField Microsoft Word for Email.

The format that we have is `fmDD"{sup|er}" month YYYY`

This is the format that we currently use
and wondering if there is a way for this to be corrected in the Word file

`{MERGEFIELD theDate}` We use this on the Microsoft Word file but it didn't work.
The result is at it is `1{sup|er} janvier 2012`.

The Expected behavior is
**1<sup>er</sup> janvier 2012** for the Microsft Word.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?70336-Macro-to-superscript-ordinal-date-numbers-%93st%94-%93nd%94-%93rd%94-%93th%94. Look also at my Add-In which includes ordinal dates. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#LegalToolbars. The macro would be run on a final merge result document. See also my page on Date Fields and their formatting: https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart

Comment: To see how to do this and just about everything else you might want to do with dates in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html 
or:
http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party
In particular, look at the item titled *Insert A Date with Ordinal Numbering*. No macros required. Do read the document's introductory material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This takes a complex field with text already formatted as superscript in the field.

From [my page on Date Fields in Microsoft Word](https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart) is the following field structure.

> {QUOTE{CREATEDATE @ "dddd 'the' d"}{IF{=(MOD({={CREATEDATE @
> d}+89},100)>2)*(MOD({={CREATEDATE @ d}+9},10)<3)}= 1
> {=MOD({CREATEDATE @ d},10)-2 # rd;st;nd} th}{CREATEDATE @ "' of'
> MMMM, yyyy"}}

Here is a screenshot of the field which shows the superscripting:

[image: screenshot of field code]

This field is from [my Legal Toolbars Add-In](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#LegalToolbars) as a superscripted CreateDate. It is an AutoText entry there. Here is a screenshot from the Add-In menu.

[image: screenshot from Add-In]

You could try to modify it to use your mergefield instead of CREATEDATE.

```
{QUOTE{MERGEFIELD theDate \@ "dddd 'the' d"}{IF{=(MOD({={MERGEFIELD theDate \@ d}+89},100)>2)*(MOD({={MERGEFIELD theDate \@ d}+9},10)<3)}= 1 {=MOD({v \@ d},10)-2 \# rd;st;nd} th}{MERGEFIELD theDate \@ "' of' MMMM, yyyy"}}
```

(I have not tried this with a merge field. You would need to superscript parts as shown in the screenshot.)

This was based on Paul Edstein (macropod)'s work, in particular, his [Date Calculation Tutorial](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html). If you want to understand this, I recommend downloading that tutorial and going through it. If you do, pay attention especially to the introductory part. It has multiple date calculation fields which are very complex.

Refer to my [page on date fields](https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart) for more. You cannot simply type the braces. Word must insert them. See also: my article on [Dealing with Fields in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you hoped that Word's "field language" would be similar to something you are familiar with. But for example {sup|er} doesn't mean anything in Word's "field language".

To make this work for dates in the French language, I suggest you start by experimenting with the following fields and formatting.

```
{SET xDate {MERGEFIELD theDate}}{SET ordText {={xDate \@D}-2 \#e;er}}{xDate \@D}{ordText}{xDate \@" MMMM YYYY"}
```

*All* the `{}` need to be the special field code braces that you can insert on the Windows Desktop version of Word using ctrl-F9.

Then, select the field `{ordText}` and format it as superscripted text.

I may well have got some details wrong. But if you need this to work in languages other than French, you would have to ensure that you mapped each date in the month to the appropriate ordinal text, e.g. in English, the 1st, 21st and 3st should have "st", the 11th needs "th" and so on, whereas in French the 1st needs "er" and everything else needs "e"